# Why doesn't npm install globally (shouldn't it install locally by default)?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I need to install some packages via npm. I navigate to the target folder and use `npm install mypackage`. Sadly, it will be installed globally. Why? How to avoid? Do I maybe need to specify a package.json (I shouldn't).

Though, I get warnings. Here's a extract form my shell:

```
> npm-components git:(STAGING) ✗ npm install tippy.js@2.6.0
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/[my-user]/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/[my-user]/package.json'
npm WARN [my-user] No description
npm WARN [my-user] No repository field.
npm WARN [my-user] No README data
npm WARN [my-user] No license field.

+ tippy.js@2.6.0
updated 1 package and audited 5526 packages in 6.874s
found 323 vulnerabilities (103 low, 127 moderate, 93 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Comment: Wait, to make a package global, you use the -g flag with the command. Why are packages going global without it?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm currently wondering :)

Comment: I added some trace from the shell. As you can see, I'm in local npm-components. But after installing, it's empty. Instead, the package is installend in my root/home directory.

Comment: Maybe, you can try doing `npm init` in your target folder first.

Comment: @Frost that did the trick, thank you! Do you want to add the 'official' answer or do you prefer me to do it?

Comment: Sure I'll add an official answer.

Answer (score 1):

A work-around sort of solution get through the problem would be to run `npm init` in your target folder. That would generate a package.json for that folder. I yet don't know exactly why your npm is directly going global.